# Intermittent 403 errors for all users on local network after storm

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mikrotik-routeros

After returning from a cross-country drive, during which no one was in the office nor was anyone accessing the computers and devices on the office network, we are experiencing intermittent HTTP-403 errors on all PCs, tablets and devices.  The PCs run CentOS Linux, Ubuntu Linux, or Windows 10.  Tablets are both Android and IOS.

When a web page does not load, hitting refresh a few times will make it load. Secure sites will end up repeatedly asking for credentials (as if they lost the already active ones).  This even happens when logging into the web interface of the local router (After I log in, the system will periodically re-display the login page, which I can either get past by logging in again or by clicking refresh a time or two).

I have tried the obvious... I power cycled everything. I re-verified that our public IP remained the same as is set in our Mikrotik router.

I even tried the non-obvious... I manually inspected all connections in the network to make sure there were no ethernet loops (there were none).

Local PC logs display nothing as errors other than the 403 errors.  Pinging and tracerouting remote sites works consistently and does not experience any obvious errors.

My network is 192.168.28.0/24 using 8.8.8.8 for DNS. The router is a Mikrotik running RouterOS 6.43.2. Most switches are Netgear ProSafe Gigabit, and I use Ubiquiti WAPs.

Based on the above, I am reasonably certain that the issue is internal-- I have been in IT for more than two decades, so I am rather annoyed with myself that I have not figured out what the issue is yet-- thus I ask the brain trust of SuperUser for advice.....?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try a different router, it may have been damaged during the storm.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect time setting will causes secure sites asking for credentials.

Check the time of your router is correct.